# How to connect to autosys box using java

Tags: java, autosys

I have a few set of jobs scheduled in a autosys box.I want to make a java code to connect to the host where the autosys job executes.And be able to execute autosys commands.Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Autosys Java API. Contact your Autosys SA and have him download the API Reference guide from ca.com for you.